# Kerberos username using javascript

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, kerberos

Is there a way to get the kerberos username using javascript/greasemonkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Kerberos transactions take place at a lower level and are not accessible to a web page (which is all JavaScript and Greasemonkey see).  If the username ***was*** accessible, it would be a security hole to be plugged ASAP.

If an SSO system uses a web page to obtain the username (which may be the same as the Active-Directory or Kerberos username), then JS/GM can see that.  But a properly implemented Kerberos system collects the username in a special, privileged dialog.

Comment: Yup - the only way to make the username accessible to JS would be to have the text embedded somewhere in the page.